# OpenCV's Warp Affine Has Lower Quality Compared to Photoshop

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to transform and align a detected face (320x240 Size) from a CelebA image (1024x1024 Size) using OpenCV's `cv2.warpAffine` function but the quality of the transformed image is significantly lower than when I try to align it by hand in Photoshop: (Left Image Is Transformed By Photoshop & Right Image Is Transformed in OpenCV)

[image: Left Image Is Transformed By Photoshop & Right Image Is Transformed in OpenCV]

I have used all of the interpolation techniques of OpenCV but none of them came close in quality to Photoshop.

The code I'm using is:

```
warped = cv2.warpAffine(image, TRANSFORM_MATRIX, (240, 320), flags=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

What could be wrong that made the transformed image have such low quality?

Here's a [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXhEY.jpg) to the original 1024x1024 image if needed.

Comment: you need to filter out high frequency components before "decimating". it doesn't do that, not even with lanczos. apply an appropriate gaussian blur before.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz is right. However I'd suggest to apply blur **after** the affine transformation, not before.

Comment: no. *after* decimation the damage is already done. you can't fix that up anymore. stuff already fell through the cracks (sampling grid). you must lowpass *before* decimating.

Comment: I've just checked... cv.resize with INTER_AREA gives a decent result... but warpAffine **doesn't** appear to support INTER_AREA. I see previous questions where people have trouble with warpAffine and INTER_AREA... might be a bug. it's certainly not documented afaics.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477478/opencv-warpaffine-ignores-flags-cv2-inter-area

Comment: Since this "fake" INTER_AREA isn't currently documented, I've opened an issue for it. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21060 if you think you'd like to make a pull request for some changes in the docs, go ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem and general solution

You are down-sampling a signal.

The approach is always the same:

- lowpass to remove high frequency components
- resample/decimate

#### What not to do

If you *don't* do the lowpass, you'll get *aliasing*. You noticed that. Aliasing means the sampling step can completely miss some high frequency component (edge/corner/point/...), giving those strange artefacts. A properly resampled image would not *completely lose* such high frequency features.

If you do the lowpass *after* resampling, it won't fix the issue, only hide it. The damage has already been done.

You can convince yourself of both these aspects if you downsample some regular grid of strongly contrasting lines. Try alternating single-pixel lines of black and white for most effect.

#### Implementations

Libraries such as PIL do the lowpass implicitly before resampling.

**OpenCV does not** (kinda, in general). Not even with Lanczos interpolation (in OpenCV) will you be able to skip the lowpassing, because OpenCV's Lanczos has a fixed coefficient.

OpenCV has **`INTER_AREA`**, which is a *linear* interpolation, but it *additionally* sums over all pixels that are in the area between the corner samples (instead of just sampling those four corners). This **can** spare you the extra lowpass step.

here's the result of `cv.resize(im, (240, 240), interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)`:

[image: resize]

Here's the result of `cv.warpAffine(im, M[:2], (240, 240), interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)` with `M = np.eye(3) * 0.25` (equivalent scaling):

[image: warpAffine]

It appears that `warpAffine` **can't** do `INTER_AREA`. That sucks for you :/

If you need to downsample with OpenCV, and it's a *power of two*, you can use `pyrDown`. That does the lowpass and decimation... for a factor of two. Repeated application gives you higher powers.

If you need arbitrary downsampling and you don't like `INTER_AREA` for some reason, you'd have to apply a `GaussianBlur` to the input. Sigma needs to be (inversely) proportional to the scale factor. There is some relation between the gaussian filter's sigma and the resulting cutoff frequency. You'll want to investigate that some more, if you don't want to pick a value arbitrarily. Check out the kernel for `pyrDown`, and what gaussian sigma it matches best. That's probably a good value for a scale factor of 0.5, and other factors should be (inversely) proportional.

For simple downscaling, one gaussian blur would be fine. For affine warps and higher transformations, you'd need to apply lowpassing that respects the different scale for every single pixel that is looked up, because their "support" in the source image isn't square any longer, maybe not even rectangular, but an arbitrary quad!

#### What am I not saying?

This goes for *down*-sampling. If you *up*-sample, do *not* lowpass.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you elaborate a bit more on the effect of inversely proportional Sigma value with the same picture to see the effect it has on downscaling the image?

Comment: if you decimate a picture by 10x, i.e. scale factor 0.1, you'd want a sigma around 10. if you decimate by 2x, i.e. scale factor 0.5, you'd want a sigma around 2.

Comment: And is there a Visualization somewhere around the net that shows the effect of the proper Sigma value on the downscaled image? It'd really help to understand it better.